# How to deal with overdispersion with glmmTMB for generalized linear models

Tags: generalized-linear-model, validation, zero-inflation, overdispersion, glmmtmb

I'll try to make it as brief as possible.
I'm trying to fit a glm to echolocation clicks count data using the `glmmTMB` function. I started with a Poisson glm and obtained the dispersion parameter (dp) both manually (Sum of squares of Pearson Residuals / residual df) and using the DHARMa function `testDispersion`. I got a dp of >1500 so there's obvious over-dispersion.
I did the same thing with a negative binomial glm but now the dp was around 0.67 and testDispersion confirmed it was significant. Since I have count data and I have a lot of zeros, around 98% of my data, I though of passing to the zero inflated models which didn't work for ziPoisson but it kind of did with a zi negative binomial:

```r
zinb12.clicks <- glmmTMB(Clicks ~ cosTime_day + Site + sinMoon_day + 
    cosMoon_day, ziformula = ~ 1, 
    data = BaseEnv[BaseEnv$Clicks<9000, Clicks_columns], 
    family = 'nbinom2')

summary(zinb12.clicks)

Family: nbinom2  ( log )
Formula:          Clicks ~ cosTime_day + Site + sinMoon_day + cosMoon_day
Zero inflation:          ~1
Data: BaseEnv[BaseEnv$Clicks < 9000, Clicks_columns]

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 35307.7  35375.6 -17646.9  35293.7   120649 

Dispersion parameter for nbinom2 family (): 0.673 

Conditional model:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  6.312888   0.058939  107.11  < 2e-16 ***
cosTime_day  0.179152   0.050330    3.56 0.000371 ***
Site        -0.006789   0.002595   -2.62 0.008901 ** 
sinMoon_day -0.145409   0.047643   -3.05 0.002273 ** 
cosMoon_day -0.250356   0.048261   -5.19 2.13e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Zero-inflation model:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  4.44172    0.02707   164.1   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

E <- resid(zinb12.clicks, type = 'pearson')
N <- nrow(BaseEnv[BaseEnv$Clicks<9000, Clicks_columns])
k <- length(fixef(zinb12.clicks)$cond) + 
       length(fixef(zinb12.clicks)$zi)
Disp <- sum(E^2)/(N-k) #residuals sum of squares  / residual df
Disp
>1.22
testDispersion(zinb12.clicks)
DHARMa nonparametric dispersion test via sd of residuals fitted vs.
    simulated

data:  simulationOutput
dispersion = 1.5323, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

This are the plots I got:

```r
qrpois <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = modp, plot = FALSE)
plotQQunif(qrpois, main = 'Poisson')
qrzinb <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = zinb12.clicks, plot = FALSE)
plotQQunif(qrzinb, main = 'ZI negbin')
```

[image: Comparison between poisson and zinb]

```r
testOutliers(qrpois, type = 'bootstrap')
```

[image: outlier tests for poisson]

```r
testOutliers(qrzinb, type = 'bootstrap')
```

[image: outlier tests for zinb]

```r
pr <- simulateResiduals(zinb12.clicks, plot =FALSE)
plot(pr)
```

[image: DHARMa plots for residuals]

As you can see, the zinb fits pretty good to my data, except for the dispersion test. I am still not sure how to interpret the residual vs predicted plot but from what I've read the red line means there's significant deviation right?
With all this being said...my main question is ***Should I look for other distribution models or this is as good as it gets?*** as you can see I'm kind of lost right now.